# Mongodb collection.find

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm writing app in node.js and I want to write query for the find statement, but it returns everything, although in the mongo console it returns the requested query.

```
collection.find({"Messages.Id":"1"},{"Messages.$":1,_id:0},function(e,docs) {
    console.log(docs);
});
```

Anyone knows why?

(one more little question - in the mongo db the query returned only the first matching with the id, is there a way to return all?)

Update

```
{
    "Messages" : [ 
        {
             "text":"aaa",
             "Id" : [ "1", "2" ] 
        }, 
        {
             "texts" : "bbb",
             "Id" : [ "1", "3" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a sample document in the collection.

Comment: Your query would always return `all` the documents which contain a Message element with Id:1, but project only the first matching element in the `Messages` array of each document. So what is the difference that you see in the mongo shell and via node? It would be helpful if you post your expected output as well. Answering your second part of the question, To return all the Messages element, you need to remove the projection parameter from the query.

Comment: In node i see all messages printed and in mongo colnsole the first matching result

Comment: `find` operations always return a `cursor` of all matching documents.